# http: body field path 'foo' must be a non-repeated message.'

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, grpc

I'm trying to setup transcoding HTTP/JSON to gRPC with the gRPC helloworld example on gcloud endpoints.  My annotation to the `helloworld.proto` file is:

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/hello"
      body: "name"
    };
  }
}
```

and my service config is:

```
http:
  rules:

  - selector: helloworld.Greeter.SayHello
    post: /v1/hello
    body: name
```

After generating the `api_descriptor.pb` file, I execute:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy api_descriptor.pb api_config.yaml
```

and I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config. 
'ERROR: helloworld/helloworld.proto:43:3: http: body field path 'foo' must be a non-repeated message.'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the body cannot be a base type.  Wrapping the name in a message seems to work:

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/hello"
      body: "person"
    };
  }
}

message Person {
  string name = 1;
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  Person person = 1;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I recommend using `google.protobuf.StringValue` to wrap primitive string values. See https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto